# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso

I try to use `Picasso` for the first time

like in the official site example:

```
private void setItemBgImageUsingPicasso(View convertView) {
    String imageUrl = getImageUrlFromOffer(convertView);

    ImageView offerImage = ((ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.offerImage));
    Picasso.with(mOffersListActivity).load(imageUrl).into(offerImage);
}
```

but I get this error:

```
08-09 17:37:43.309: E/AndroidRuntime(17821): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
08-09 17:37:43.309: E/AndroidRuntime(17821):    at com.zoomer.general.ImageAdapter.setItemBgImageUsingPicasso(ImageAdapter.java:384)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put it in libs folder and Eclipse will pack it properly for you.

Or you leave it as it is, but go to project properties, Export tab and check the library. This way Eclipse will pack it in the final APK.

Comment: i m putting in my libs folder but its not detecting why ?

Comment: @Erum having the same noob issue have you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

if using Android Studio, I found the problem to be related to proguard so, the following fixed the issue:

1) Add this to your proguard-rules file: 
`-keep class com.squareup.picasso.** { *; }`

2) Clean the project

3) Re-build