# Only on Lollipop: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-5.0-lollipop

I encounter this problem only on lollipop version. I can run the app easily on versions above lollipop. The error shows up when I run the app in my application file:

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;
                                                                 at aroundwise.nepi.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:44)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5122)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1510)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.squareup.picasso.Picasso" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/aroundwise.nepi-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                 at aroundwise.nepi.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:44) 
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5122) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1510) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
                                                                 at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                        ... 13 more
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Here is my Application file:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static ComplexPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static MyApplication instance;
AroundWiseSDK aroundWiseSDK;
private Picasso picasso;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    sharedPreferences = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(getBaseContext(), Constants.PREFFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());

    Callbacks c = new Callbacks();
    instance = this;
    HashMap<String, String> clientData = new HashMap<>();
    clientData.put("key_placeholder", "value_placeholder");

    picasso = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext());
    aroundWiseSDK = new AroundWiseSDK(getBaseContext(), this, c, false, "https://promenada.aroundwise.com", clientData);
    aroundWiseSDK.setMainActivity(DiscoverActivity.class);
    aroundWiseSDK.bindBackgroundService();


}

public Picasso getPicasso() {
    return picasso;
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
  //  MultiDex.install(base);
}


public static ComplexPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context context) {
    if (sharedPreferences == null) {
        sharedPreferences = ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(context, Constants.PREFFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    return sharedPreferences;
}
```

}

This is my gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
    // quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.6.2'
}
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.DSA'
    exclude 'AUTHORS'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor' // butterknife
    exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.SF'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "aroundwise.nepi"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.1.8"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        //multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
      // multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')

    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       // multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
  //      multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')

    }
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def apk = output.outputFile;
        def newName;

        if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
            newName = apk.name.replace("app-debug", "-release-Nepi" + "-v" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk");
        } else {
            newName = apk.name.replace("app-debug.apk", "-Nepi" + "-v" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk");
        }


        output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName);

        if (variant.buildType.zipAlignEnabled) {
            output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName.replace("-unaligned", ""));
        }

        logger.info('INFO: Set outputFile to ' + output.outputFile + " for [" + variant.name + "]");
    }
}


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

//BUTTERKNIFE
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'

//MVP & ParcelablePlease & Adapter
apt 'com.hannesdorfmann.annotatedadapter:processor:1.1.1'
apt 'com.hannesdorfmann.parcelableplease:processor:1.0.2'

//AROUNDWISE SDK's
compile(name: 'aroundwisesdk', ext: 'aar')
compile(name: 'aroundwisecards', ext: 'aar')

//GOOGLE

//FACEBOOK

//ANDROID

//RETROFIT&RxANDROID

//UTIL
//compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9@aar'

//BeaconSDk needed
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.annotatedadapter:annotation:1.1.1'
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.annotatedadapter:support-recyclerview:1.1.1'
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:mvp:2.0.1'
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:viewstate:2.0.1'
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.parcelableplease:annotation:1.0.2'
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:retrofit:1.1.0'
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
compile 'com.github.jinatonic.confetti:confetti:1.0.0'
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.3-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
compile 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.daprlabs.aaron:cardstack:0.3.1-beta0'
compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.+@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}
```

And this is my manifest. I am using multidex but I do not need to extend MultiDexApplicaiton since I am using minSDK 21 ( at least that is what I understood from the documentation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="aroundwise.nepi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <permission
        android:name="aroundwise.nepi.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="aroundwise.nepi.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />


    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.mainActivity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="5ef18a8d1003a5ed11bbf50f188bc758133cba38" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.onBoardActivity.OnBoardActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.discoverActivity.DiscoverActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_api_key_me" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.cameraActivity.CameraActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider840752006058179"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            tools:replace="android:theme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="aroundwise.nepi.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".gcm.PushNotificationListener"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".gcm.GcmIdListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".gcm.GCMRegistationIntentService"
            android:exported="false"></service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I ran out of ideas, so please any help or tips are welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm having same problems

Comment: I think this helped me : -keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.** Write them in the progruard-rules

Answer (score 8):

If `publishNonDefault true` was defined in libs build.gradle, please remove it or make it false. Please try. I have resolved this issue by removing  `publishNonDefault true` in build.gradle of lib which occurred `NoClassDefFoundError`.

If not working, please add

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries false
}
```

Comment: this saved us big time, thanks for the inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814593/android-app-crash-noclassdeffounderror-on-samsung-lollipop-devices

Comment: Thank you, worked for me too! Worked on Marshmallow and newer but immediately got the crash on Lollipop when setting minSdk = 21.

Comment: Also had to disable Instant Run when deploying on Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fabric then please remove dependency of picasso from gradle, it will work fine.Try it...

Comment: I have tried, I get Error:(10, 28) error: package com.squareup.picasso does not exist.

Comment: Then try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225327/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-squareup-picasso-picasso

Comment: Actually it helped, but now I get a second error, almost the same but with :Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;. It crashes when I use the constructor of a class in a library I imported through a aar file :     compile(name: 'aroundwisesdk', ext: 'aar'). But now the proguard does not fix the problem :(

Comment: can you remove multidexEnabled=true ?

Comment: and if not, then try to put compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' // or 1.0.1

Comment: I tried to remove multiDexEnabled and It crashes(64k method error). And I also added the 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'. Still not working :(

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578135/noclassdeffounderror-for-okhttpclient

Answer (score -1):

You need to install `Multidex` to run `picasso` on lower devices

public class MyApplication extends Application {

```
 @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(base);
   }
}
```

add this in your `manifest` under `application` tag

```
android:name="your.package.name.MyApplication"
```

Comment: I do not need lower than 5.0. And what I read on the documentation I only need to specify multiDexEnabled true, don't need to install Multidex. Anyway I tried that way too, but it did not worked. Thanks for the tip